# How to implement AND logic in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have a SQL query that I'm trying to translate into Lambda, however the **and** clause has stumped me. I'm having no luck on researching how to do this **and** clause on lambda. How would you guys approach making this sql statement using lambda?

```
SELECT distinct x.* 
FROM UserInteractions x
JOIN UserInteractions x2 on x.sourceuser_id = x2.targetuser_id and x.targetuser_id = x2.sourceuser_id
WHERE x.sourceuser_id = 2
```

Here is my original join, but i don't know how to add the "add"

```
query = query.Join(db.UserInteractions,
                x => x.SourceUser,
                x2 => x2.TargetUser,
                (x, x2) => new { x, x2 }).Where(f => f.x.SourceUser == user).Select(p => p.x);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an anonymous type for the join

```
from x in UserInteractions
join x2 in UserInteractions 
on new {x.sourceuser_id, x.targetUser_id} equals new {x2.sourceuser_id, x2.targetuser_id}
select new .... blah blah
```

or...

```
UserInteractions
   .Join (
      UserInteractions , 
      x => 
         new  
         {
            x.sourceuser_id, 
            x.targetuser_id
         }, 
      x2 => 
         new  
         {
            x2.sourceuser_id, 
            x2.targetuser_id
         }, 
      (x, x2) => //Whatever it is you want to project out....
   )
```

Comment: How would you translate that into lambda?